# Text overlay on Image in Xamarin form using PCL

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to do Text overlay on Image in Xamarin form using PCL project as in the image below

[image]

I created the replative layout to do this, Can any one suggest how could i format the text?

```
 var myLabel = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Hello World",
            Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(20),
            TextColor = Color.White,
            XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
            YAlign = TextAlignment.Center
        };

        var stack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {myLabel}
        };

        var slayout = new ContentView
        {
            BackgroundColor = new Color(0,0,0,.5),
            Content = stack
        };

        var myImage = new Image()
        {
            Source = "deal1.png"
        };

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout();

        layout.Children.Add(myImage,
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width; }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Height; }));

        layout.Children.Add(slayout,
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width; }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Height; }));
```

Comment: it's not clear what is it you're asking - layout or label formatting?

Comment: I need to add text overlay on the image, as in the attachment.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you should use **AbsoluteLayout** instead of RelativeLayout?

Comment: @ FredyWenger- Do you have any sample source code for that?

Answer (score 1):

I would write something that would look like that (customize with more bindable properties and labels with regards to the different elements of your overlayed text, as well as bindable properties for your label background color and opacity).

```
public class OverlayedImage : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty SourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Source), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(OverlayedImage));
        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(OverlayedImage));
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (propertyName == SourceProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                _image.Source = Source;
            }
            else if (propertyName == TextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                _label.Text = Text;
            }
            else
                base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }


        private readonly Image _image =new Image();
        private readonly Label _label = new Label();

        public OverlayedImage()
        {
            var abs = new AbsoluteLayout();
            abs.Children.Add(_image, new Rectangle(0, 0 , 1 , 1), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            abs.Children.Add(_label, new Rectangle(0, 1, 1, 0.5), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            Content = abs;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How can I use this inside stack layout?

Comment: Like any other element.